# Slow network connection speed with berkeley sockets

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, buffer, download

My friend and I have wrote a small download manager in C that splits the target file into several parts and downloads each part using a single posix thread. Everything seems to work fine, except that it is very slow compared to other download managers like wget (which as I know, does not split the file into several chunks). In every thread, we use a simple loop to download each part from a socket:

```
while ((nrecv = recv(sockfd, downbuf, sizeof(downbuf), 0)) > 0)
{
    if ((nwrite = write(fd, downbuf, nrecv)) != nrecv)
        die("write");

    totalrw += nwrite;
}
    /* ... */
```

I've tried with several different sizes for "downbuf", like 2014, 2048, 4096 and 8192, but with not much difference. It takes almost 45 seconds to download a 270 MB file, while wget downloads the same file in just 5 seconds. Both server and client are on the same host. Why is the difference so vast? Could you please tell me what trick wget uses?

This is how I make the request to the server:

```
sockfd = make_conn(website);

hdr.rq_buf = headerbuf; /* buffer to save response header */
hdr.rq_bufsize = sizeof(headerbuf);
hdr.rq_host = website;
hdr.rq_fpath = filepath; /* target file */
hdr.rq_flags = S_HEADFLAG; /* use head method at this moment
                 to get the total file size */

error = headerinit(hdr);

if (error)
{
    die("headerinit()");
}

send(sockfd, headerbuf, strlen(headerbuf), 0); /* send the initial request */

recv(sockfd, respbuf, sizeof(respbuf), 0);

if (-1 == response_proc(respbuf, strlen(respbuf), &resp))
{
    myperror("response_proc()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} /* process the header */

size_t sz = (size_t)strtol(resp.rs_content_length, NULL, 10);

divide(sz, chunks, numcons); /* divide the file into several parts */

for (int i = 0; i < numcons; i++)
{
            /* populate data needed for threads */
    args[i].t_hdr.rq_offset.c_start = chunks[i].c_start; /* where to start */
    args[i].t_hdr.rq_offset.c_end = chunks[i].c_end; /* download up to this point */
    args[i].t_hdr.rq_host = strdup(website);
    args[i].t_hdr.rq_fpath = strdup(filepath);

    snprintf(args[i].t_fname, BUFSIZ, "%sp%i", outfile, i);

    args[i].t_order = i;

}

for (i = 0; i < numcons; i++)
{


    if (0 != pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_main,
                &args[i]))
    {
        die("pthread_create()");
    }

}

for (i = 0; i < numcons; i++)
{

    if (0 != pthread_join(threads[i], &thread_status))
    {
        die("pthread_join()");
    }

}
```

http_request_header_t is defined as:

```
typedef struct {
    void        *rq_buf;
    size_t       rq_bufsize;
    char        *rq_host;
    char        *rq_fpath;
    chunk_t      rq_offset;
    int      rq_flags;
} http_request_header_t;
```

and http_response_header_t is defined as:

```
    typedef struct {
#ifdef WITH_EXTRA_HEADERS
    char    *rs_version;
#endif
    char    *rs_status;
    char    *rs_date;
    char    *rs_server;
    char    *rs_last_modified;
    char    *rs_accept_ranges;
    char    *rs_content_length;
    char    *rs_connection;
    char    *rs_content_type;
} http_response_header_t;
```

This is the main routine that every thread use:

```
    void *
thread_main(void *arg_orig)
{
    thr_arg_t *arg = (thr_arg_t*)arg_orig;

    int fd, sockfd;

    http_response_header_t resp;

    size_t totalrw = 0;
    ssize_t nrecv;

    char *line = malloc(BUFSIZ * sizeof(char));

    char hdrbuf[BUFSIZ];
    char respbuf[BUFSIZ];

    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP;

    ssize_t nwrite = 0;

    void *downbuf = malloc(DOWNBUF * sizeof(char));

    sockfd = make_conn(arg->t_hdr.rq_host);

    fd = open(arg->t_fname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_EXCL, mode);

    if (-1 == fd)
    {
        die("thread_open(): fd");
    }

    arg->t_hdr.rq_flags = S_OFFSET;
    arg->t_hdr.rq_buf = hdrbuf;
    arg->t_hdr.rq_bufsize = sizeof(hdrbuf);

    headerinit(arg->t_hdr);
    //printf("%s\n", arg->t_hdr.rq_buf);

    sendn(sockfd, hdrbuf, strlen(hdrbuf), 0);
         /* first, read the header */
    while ((nrecv = readheader(sockfd, &line, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
    {
        strncpy(respbuf + nwrite, line, sizeof(respbuf) - nwrite);
        nwrite += nrecv;
    }

    nwrite = 0;

    //printf("\n\n%s\n\n", respbuf);


    if (-1 == response_proc(respbuf, strlen(respbuf), &resp))
    {
        myperror("thread_response_proc()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (strncmp(resp.rs_status, "416", 3) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Partial content is not supported by the server\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
            /* now read the actual data */
    while ((nrecv = recv(sockfd, downbuf, sizeof(downbuf), 0)) > 0)
    {

        if ((nwrite = write(fd, downbuf, nrecv)) != nrecv)
            die("write");

        totalrw += nwrite;
    }
    if(-1 == nrecv)
    {
        die("recv()");
    }

    close(sockfd);
    close(fd);

    idxwr(arg->t_fname, arg->t_order, totalrw);

    return ((void*)0);
}
```

Comment: I think you should also post how you build your download requests.

Comment: @holgac, I've posted the bulk of code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted enough here, but usually the cause of an unexpected slowdown in TCP will be [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). This is triggered when you write small chunks of data to a socket. These would be inefficient to put on the wire on their own so the TCP stack waits for the user program to add more data before it sends out the packet. Only if nothing is added for 'a while' does it actually send an incomplete packet.

This can be disabled, but as your aim is an efficient bulk transfer you probably shouldn't.